# How to parse XML document without closing tags (python)?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to read an xml document that does not appear to have closing tags.  I did not make this XML document, but I'm downloading it from the following location:

```
import ftplib
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

filename = 'FBOFeed20170509'

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.fbo.gov')
ftp.login(user = '', passwd = '')

localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)

ftp.quit()
localfile.close()

tree = et.parse(filename)

for node in tree.iter():
    print (node.tag, node.attrib)
```

And here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 18, in <module>
tree = et.parse(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1184, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 596, in parse
self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 24, column 2
```

So I opened the file with a text editor to take a look, and see there are no closing tags.  Here are the first 24 lines:

```
<PRESOL>
<DATE>0509
<YEAR>17
<AGENCY>Department of the Air Force
<OFFICE>Air Education and Training Command
<LOCATION>Luke AFB Contracting Squadron
<ZIP>85309
<CLASSCOD>Z
<NAICS>238320
<OFFADD>14100 W. Eagle Street Luke AFB AZ 85309
<SUBJECT>Painting IDIQ Luke AFB
<SOLNBR>FA488717R0005
<CONTACT>Justin A Cheeks, Phone 8566232747, Email justin.cheeks@us.af.mil
<DESC>The 56th ...
<LINK>
<URL>https://www.fbo.gov/spg/USAF/AETC/LukeAFBCS/FA488717R0005/listing.html
<DESC>Link To Document
<SETASIDE>Service-Disabled Veteran-Owned Small Business
<POPCOUNTRY>US
<POPZIP>85309
<POPADDRESS>14100 W Eagle Street (B-26)

Luke AFB, AZ
</PRESOL>
```

I guess the error is related to the fact that PRESOL is closed with /PRESOL, but none of the other tags are closed.  This is a straightforward entry, some of the others include various HTML tags in the DESC or CONTACT portions so I'm not sure how I could write something to close the tags before I parse, for example here is another portion of the file:

```
<CONTACT>Tammy Davis
Tammy.Davis6@va.gov

<a href="mailto:tammy.davis6@va.gov">Tammy.Davis6@va.gov</a>
<DESC>The purpose...
```

I'm not sure if all of the tags are in the same order or even the same for each entry.  Is this even an XML format?  Is there a different python library I should be using here?

Comment: This is not an XML file. By definition XML is well-formed and Python's `etree` is correctly erring out during the parsing. Correspond with your vendor on this markup.

Comment: Thanks - this is publicly available data from the Federal Government and unfortunately I can't find any documentation.

Comment: how about parsing it line by line like a regular file?

Comment: This is easy to parse if you know all of the `<XXX>` tags. Nominally, you could just start a new key/value pair each time you see a tag at the start of the line, but since a value may have embedded html tags, you need a way to skip false positives.

Comment: My guess is that once you've read through a couple of these, the list of allowed tags is clear (this likely comes from a database and those are column names). With a bit of poking around, it seems this type of FBO info is available from other sites. Like maybe this https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/federal-business-opportunities-data (but I didn't look too hard!)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/presidential-innovation-fellows/fbo-parser Parses the daily FBO file into JSON which adds the closing tags to the fields within the notice types.  I use it then convert it to an XML file to import data into my database.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through the same issue recently. Below the piece of code I used to save all "PRESOL" (i.e., presolicitation notices) into a .csv file

```
tags = ["DATE","YEAR","AGENCY","OFFICE","LOCATION","ZIP",
    "CLASSCOD","OFFADD","SUBJECT","SOLNBR","RESPDATE","ARCHDATE",
    "CONTACT","CONTACTDESC","LINK","URL","URLDESC"]
for y in range(2005,2019):
    outfile =  'my_dir/FBO' + str(y) + '.csv' # output file 
    yearterm = 'FBOFeed' + str(y) + '*'
    counter = 0
    with open(outfile, 'w+') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        writer.writerow(tags)
        for csvfile in glob.glob(yearterm):
            inpresol = 0
            oldtag = '' # initiate the definition of old tag
            with open(csvfile, 'r+', encoding="latin_1") as f:
                for line in f:
                    tag = line[line.find("<")+1:line.find(">")] # find the line tag
                    if tag == "DESC": # there are multiple "DESC" tags, take care of them
                        dicttag = oldtag + tag
                    else:
                        dicttag = tag

                if "<PRESOL>" in line: # start of the record: initiate the dictionary
                    d = {x : [] for x in tags}    
                    inpresol = 1
                    continue
                elif "</PRESOL>" in line: # end of the record
                    writer.writerow([d["DATE"],d["YEAR"],d["AGENCY"],d["OFFICE"],
                                     d["LOCATION"],d["ZIP"],d["CLASSCOD"],d["OFFADD"],
                                     d["SUBJECT"],d["SOLNBR"],d["RESPDATE"],
                                     d["ARCHDATE"],d["CONTACT"],d["CONTACTDESC"],d["LINK"],
                                     d["URL"],d["URLDESC"]])
                    inpresol = 0
                    continue

                if inpresol == 1: # store the results
                    tagged_tag = "<" + tag + ">"
                    newline = line.replace(tagged_tag, "")
                    d[dicttag] = newline
                    oldtag = tag
            f.close()
    g.close()
```

I know that it is not much "pythonic", but it works pretty well and stores yearly files with the record in .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to create end-tags and do something like this:

```
text = re.sub(r"<(\w+)>\s+([^<]+|)", r"<\1>\2</\1>", text)
text = re.sub(r"<PRESOL>\s*</PRESOL>", "<PRESOL>", text)
```